# Implementing MPOAuth in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, oauth

I have been all around the web trying to find resources on how to use MPOAuthMobile framework, to integrate OAuth to my iPhone app.

Th wiki here: http://code.google.com/p/mpoauthconnection/wiki/MPOAuthMobile says nothing about the configuration.
I compiled the sample and added my endpoints to the oauthAutoConfig.plist and RootViewController. The requestToken goes fine and a unauthorized token is returned from my server.

The next thing is the framework opens the user access request to a page in Safari, not in a UIWebView as the wiki says.

Even after successfull login (via the web form) the verification code is posted back to the browser.

The framework never requests the accessToken.

There is a lot of code (that looks like it can do everything automatically) but i cant figure out how to configure the framework.

**My initial goal** is to pop the UIWebView to the user with the login form and after tapieng "login" the framework/app should pick up the accessToken it self.

Can anybody help for make MPOAuthMobile work? Has anybosy had any success with the full flow?

Kind regards
Esben

Comment: So i'm getting at it. First: I don't know why the login page redirect is not opened in the UIWebView. Instead it pushes Safari. Second: I don't seem to understand the callback_url. This will enable OAuth 1.0a and maybe solve the issue with UIWebView. In the framework the callback_url is hardcoded to @"x-com-mpoauth-mobile://success", but my server doesent implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make your app respond to the custom `x-com-mpoauth-mobile://success` make sure you have declared it in your Info.plist as follows:

[image: Info.plist screenshot]

Then implement `-(BOOL)application:handleOpenURL:` in your App Delegate and Safari should pass control back to the app when it gets the access token.

Comment: Thanks man. This is what i was looking for. There is NO documentation on this what so ever. Anyways. We've decided to go with OAuth 2 : Resource Owner Password Credentials which is much easier to comprehend and doesent need any huge framework. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.3 Keep it simple ;-)